# Docker image for Confluent - adding Confluent Hub connectors

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I wanted to slightly modify Confluent's Git repo `Dockerfile` to have in my Confluent Connect page mongoDB and Snowflake connections. Everything runs ok but I don't see them in the portal.

Should `docker-compose.yml` be modified as well?

Original code:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:5.5.1

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

ARG CONNECTOR_NAME
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/${CONNECTOR_NAME}:5.5.0
```

Moded code:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:5.5.1

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

ARG CONNECTOR_NAME
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/${CONNECTOR_NAME}:5.5.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.2.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:1.4.3
```

Comment: `Unable to parse plugin id, make sure it has format: <owner>/<name>:<version|latest>` is the error I also got while trying to build the file.

Comment: Please provide your docket-compose.yml

Comment: And your docker building command

Comment: https://github.com/marcin2x4/confluentlearn/find/master

Comment: $ docker build github.com/marcin2x4/confluentlearn/find/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to do the following.

1. Modify your `Dockerfile`:

```yml
FROM confluentinc/cp-server-connect-base:5.5.1

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.2.0 \
   && confluent-hub install --no-prompt snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:1.4.3
```

Since you need to install only `mongodb` and `snowflake` connectors.

2. Use your custom image in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
...
  connect:
    # image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.3.2-5.5.0
    build: .
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
...
```

Comment: First part done but I have no idea how to create docker-compose file.

Comment: Add lines from here https://github.com/meddlin/cpat/blob/9c510c785e1c2b8a944702c740eeb084965be4ac/docs/event-stream-layer/development-environment/docker-compose.yml#L57-L59

Comment: You mean only lines 57-59?

Comment: I found instruction for your case: https://github.com/meddlin/cpat/blob/9c510c785e1c2b8a944702c740eeb084965be4ac/docs/event-stream-layer/notes/confluent-getting-started.md#use-custom-kafka-image-in-kafka-docker-compose

Comment: So you can build you own kafka connect image with tag (e.g. my-custom-image:1.0.0) and then use it in docker-compose. Or directly tell to docker-compose to build image (see my answer)

Comment: We are almost there Alexander! I see both connectors in control center of Confluent's ;)

Comment: Intresting thing is that when I added `&& confluent-hub install --no-prompt snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:1.4.3` line to your Dockerfile file everything worked. When I did same on previous files not all components got installed. Not that it does matter but worth mentioning.